# What does Windows folder/file encryption exactly mean?

Tags: security, windows-11, window

I use Windows explorer (in Windows 11) folder properties to encrypt a folder and its files.

1. In the process no password was setup. I was able to login to my computer using a *different user* and still was able to see the content of the files. So what is the encryption used for? Only if someone steals my hard drive cannot see the folder's content?
2. What is the security level of folder/file encryption? can a rookie hacker still see the folder/files?

Comment: Have you used the same password for the other user account as to your own?

Comment: Windows EFS is a multi-user/group file encryption system. If the second used had access when you enabled encryption using the first user then a second key for file access was automatically addde for that second user, too.

Comment: @harrymc good question . Answer is Yes

Answer (score 0):

File encryption in windows is called EFS. It uses certificates to encrypt with, so no passwords needs to be entered. No, a 2nd user will not be able to read the files unless he is the EFS recovery agent user or you intentionally added his certificate (which you didn't).

So I assume you only think that the file got encrypted but it did not. Please verify if the file/folder has changed its color to green in explorer.

Comment: No folder is not green. Should it be? I followed all encryption steps.

Comment: Look, by default, encrypted files/folders will wear green. See an example here: https://www.top-password.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/windows-shows-file-name-in-color.png So unless you changed folder options, it should be green. Check: Click Start, and then click Control Panel.


2. Click Appearance and Themes, and then click Folder Options.


3. On the View tab, see if "Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color" check box is checked (it should be).

Comment: @SNash As far as I know file and folder coloring for EFS or compressed files is disabled by default on modern Windows versions. You have to enable it in Explorer options.